# What's difference between Factory.build and Factory.attributes_for?

Tags: ruby, rspec2, factory-bot

In our rspec test for rails 3.1.0 app, we use both Factory.build and Factory.attributes_for. What we found is that if we change the Factory.build to Factory.attributes_for, one case for data validation failed. Furthermore the Factory.attributes_for did not test it right. I am wondering what's the difference between those two and, how to use them in rspec.

In our model test, we are using Factory.build. In controller test for update or new, we use Factory.attributes_for. we just found out a case in controller test that Factory.attributes_for did not test it right and failed the case which has passed in model validation with Factory.build.

Thanks so much.

UPDATE:
Here is a rspec case in rfq model:

```
  it "should not have nil in report_language if need_report is true" do
    rfq = Factory.build(:rfq, :need_report => true, :report_language => nil)
    rfq.should_not be_valid
  end
```

Here is a rspec case in rfq controller:

```
it "should be successful for corp head" do
  session[:corp_head] = true
  session[:user_id] = 1
  s = Factory(:standard)
  rfq = Factory.attributes_for(:rfq, :need_report => true, :report_language => 'EN')
  rfq[:standard_ids] = [s.id] # attach standard_id's to mimic the POST'ed form data
  get 'create', :rfq => rfq
  response.should redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=RFQ saved!")  
end
```

The controller case above failed because of the validation failure. The failure in controller case is caused by addition of the line below to the create of controller rfqs.

```
  @rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:need_report]
```

However the case in rfq model (see above for rfq model) has passed successfully. It is .build in model test and .attributes_for in controller test.

UPDATE:

The right statement should be:

```
@rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:rfq][:need_report] == 'true'
```

OR

```
@rfq.report_language = nil if params[:rfq][:need_report] == 'false'
```

`params[:need_report]` returns nothing and is not the right way to retrieve data from the params.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Factory.attributes_for` simply returns a hash of the attributes for the `Factory. Factory.build` uses these same assets, but returns an instance of your class with those same attributes set.

```
Factory.build(:user)
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
User.new(Factory.attributes_for(:user))
```

but you'll see they're not interchangeable. Maybe if you post some of your code we can better explain what's going on in your tests.

Comment: I fired up the console and it is as what you explained. .build returns an instance of the object, with every field in table and id. .attributes_for ONLY returns the fields defined in Factory, with no id.

Comment: @user938363 Shouldn't `@rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:need_report]` be `@rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:rfq][:need_report]` ?